# There is only one function satisfying $\int_0^xf(t)dt \geq f(x) , \forall x\in[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $A$ be the set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to [0, \infty)$ satisfying 
$\displaystyle\int_0^x f(t)dt\geq f(x), \ \  \forall  x \in [0,1]$. Prove that $|A|=1$.

Proof:

$f(x)=0, \forall x\in[0,1]$ satisfies the condition. We show that this is the only function possible.

Suppose the contrary. So, $\exists \ c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=k > 0$. By neighbourhood property of continuous functions, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that $f(t)>0, \ \ \forall t \in [c-\delta,c]\subset [0,1]$. Let $\inf_{t\in[c-\delta,c]} f(t) =m_c >0 $ [since it has to attain its infimum in $[c-\delta,c]$ so it must be greater than $0$].

So, $\displaystyle\int_0^{c-\delta}f(t)dt+\int_{c-\delta}^cf(t)dt\geq\int_{c-\delta}^cf(t)dt\geq m_c\delta \geq f(c)$  i.e.,

a contradiction to our assumption since $f(c)\geq m_c$ and $0<\delta<1$, so $f(c)>m_c\delta$. [equality cannot hold]

Is this correct? Please verify.

Comment: Since when is $\int_a^bf(f)\,dt = f(b)-f(a)$?

Comment: Choose $c$ so that $f(c)$ is the maximum of $f$.

Comment: @amsmath, I am going to shoot myself.

Comment: An easy argumentation is this: Let $c$ be the max of $f$. Then $f(x)\le\int_0^xc\,dt = cx$. Hence, $f(x)\le\int_0^xct\,dt = \frac c2 x^2\le \frac c2 x$. Going on this way, we get $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @amsmath I've corrected it. A very stupid thing to write indeed. Could you please check it now?. The argument you presented is really nice.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas It is wrong. You cannot conclude from $b\ge a$ and $b\ge c$ that $a\ge c$.

Comment: @amsmath. Thanks for pointing it out. I realized where I have gone wrong.

Comment: @amsmath  let us carry out the argument of yours to completion. Correct me if I am wrong:

The existence of such a $c$ is guaranteed since $f$ is a continuous function on a compact domain. $f(x) \leq \int_0^xf(t)dt\leq  \int_0^xcdt=cx \implies$ 

$f(x)\leq cx\implies 0\leq f(x)\leq\int_0^xf(t)dt \leq\int_0^xctdt=cx^2/2$

Suppose, $f(x)\leq cx^n/n!$. So, $f(x)\leq\int_0^xf(t)dt\leq \frac{cx^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Therefore, $0\leq f(x)\leq cx^{n}/n!\leq c/n!, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \forall x\in[0,1] $. Now, $\frac{c}{n!} \to 0,$ as $n \to \infty$. By sandwich theorem, the conclusion follows

Comment: Yes. You can make it clearer by saying $0\le f(x)\le c x^n/n!\le c/n!$.

Comment: Me idiot. It's even easier: We saw that $f(x)\le \frac c2 x^2$, so $f(x)\le\frac c2$ for all $x$. But $c$ was the max...

Comment: @amsmath since $x≤1$?

Comment: Do I have to answer that?

Comment: @amsmath Given how stupid mistakes I have been making, I can't be sure of anything anymore.